# Pyinstaller SSL error with Requests module

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, pyinstaller

I am currently trying to turn a python script I wrote into an executable using the Pyinstaller application, but I'm running into some issues. The executable is producing an SSL error (detailed error description below) whenever anytime a requests.get call is made to a REST api I'm accessing.

Error:
ssl.SSLError: [Errno 185090050] _ssl.c:340: error:0B084002:x509 certificates routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib

I'm not sure what's going wrong, and there are one or two similar topics to this one, but they didn't help me too much as they dealt with httplib2 mainly. I'll link another discussion I found on the topic.

https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/557

Also, I'm new to python so please go easy on me!

Comment: Is the `cacerts.pem` file ending up in your executable? Requests relies on it to do SSL. See [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/dev/todo/#downstream-repackaging).